# Get rows with maximum sum of 3 columns - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I am stuck with some query logic. I have a table called `student`. Table have the marks of the student of each semester. There is `n` number of semesters. I need to get the name and id of students with **highest maximum mark(mark1+mark2+mark3)** in each semester.

> This is my table structure

```
|id| name | mark1| mark2| mark3| sem|
|1 | Harry| 8    | 9    | 9    | 1  |
|2 | John | 10   | 8    | 10   | 1  |
|3 | Derek| 4    | 5    | 8    | 1  |
|4 | Dona | 8    | 9    | 5    | 1  |
|5 | Ammy | 9    | 9    | 9    | 2  |
|6 | Kate | 10   | 7    | 10   | 2  |
|7 | Aby  | 3    | 5    | 4    | 2  |
|8 | Eliza| 5    | 9    | 5    | 2  |
```

> Needed output

```
|id| name | mark1| mark2| mark3| sem| maxmark|
|2 | John | 10   | 8    | 10   | 1  |   28   |
|5 | Ammy | 9    | 9    | 9    | 2  |   27   |
|6 | Kate | 10   | 7    | 10   | 2  |   27   |
```

> MY ATTEMPT TO GET **maxmark**

```
SELECT *, (MAX(`mark1` + `mark2` + `mark3`)) AS maxmark
FROM `stud`
GROUP BY `studid`
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve the problem? It would be really helpful to you to share this with us.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I have only got the query to get maxmarks. I have updated the answer

Comment: good try @SonyPathanamthitta just need to change the group by to sem to start with...

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. What if there's a fourth mark? Or what if you want to take only the best 2 out of 3 marks for each student?

Comment: U don't bother about 4th mark. Got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It JOINs the student table to a table filled with maximum marks for each semester, only showing students who achieved the maximum mark for that semester (s2.maxmark = s1.mark1+s1.mark2+s1.mark3).

```
SELECT s1.*, s2.maxmark
FROM student s1
JOIN (SELECT sem, MAX(mark1 + mark2 + mark3) AS maxmark
      FROM student
      GROUP BY sem) s2
ON s2.sem = s1.sem AND s2.maxmark = s1.mark1+s1.mark2+s1.mark3
```

Output:

```
id  name    mark1   mark2   mark3   sem     maxmark
2   John    10      8       10      1       28
5   Ammy    9       9       9       2       27
6   Kate    10      7       10      2       27
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3277e/2)

Answer (score 1):

You have to group by sem to get the maximum marks for each sem in a sub query, once you have the max mark for each sem you could use a IN on a subquery like this,

```
SELECT *, mark1+mark2+mark3 AS maxmark 
from student
where (sem, mark1 + mark2 + mark3) in (
SELECT sem, MAX(mark1 + mark2 + mark3) AS maxmark
FROM student
GROUP BY sem )
```

output

```
|id| name | mark1| mark2| mark3| sem| maxmark|
|2 | John | 10   | 8    | 10   | 1  |   28   |
|5 | Ammy | 9    | 9    | 9    | 2  |   27   |
|6 | Kate | 10   | 7    | 10   | 2  |   27   |
```

you could learn more about in from internet, https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/in.php 
good luck, hope this helped.